Implementing the correct query in generateMetadata
I am using next js and rtk query in my project. I came across something that I need to do generateMetadata. I looked at examples and in them queries are done via Axios. I don't see the point in connecting another library for queries when I have rtk query.Maybe I'm wrong and I really should use axios or fetch.I also wanted to use rtk, so as not to make several requests. That is, I would save the data after the request to the store and then get the data from there. I don't know how correct the solution is.I would be very grateful if you could tell me what I'm doing wrong.
My rtk api
export const pastEventsApi = rtkQueryApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getVideo: builder.query<Filters, string>({
      query: (id) => ({
        url: `/pro/ru/block/get_selected_video?uid=${id}`,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});

How I tried to make a request
export const generateMetadata = async ({ params }: Params) => {
  const { id } = params;
  const res = await pastEventsApi.endpoints.getVideo.initiate(id);
  return {
    title: res?.data?.title,
  };
};


are you getting an error?

I don't see any errors, the request just doesn't work

I didn't quite get it.  I decided to make a request via RTK queries in generateMetadata for two reasons

It would be too hard for me to describe headers in axios. That is, I just use the ready-made RTK.
There is no need to make two requests. For meta data and data

What do you think, is it worth making a request via axios?
